# Excel: Match the value in a row and replace value

Tags: excel

Is it possible to select multiple rows that match a certain value and the replace the matched row values?

I have 25000 rows to work of.

For example, there are `gender` column. The original value is **1** for **male** and **2** for **female**.

Now I want to change the value **"1"** to **"male"** and value **"2"** to **"female"**.

Are there any other way to do this without going one by one?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried selecting the cells of interest and then applying the built-in find and replace utility of excel? If not, select the rows under the gender column and click control+f to pop up the find and replace dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can think of.

You could use Find and Replace Functionality

[Find and Replace](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90?ocmsassetID=HP001216390&CorrelationId=4eade763-a0f2-433e-a17f-4e34b6623d6c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Or you could use set up a small table of gender values on another sheet and use `VLOOKUP`

[VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90?ocmsassetID=HP001216390&CorrelationId=4eade763-a0f2-433e-a17f-4e34b6623d6c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[image: VLOOKUP]
<sub>(source: [tqn.com](https://0.tqn.com/d/spreadsheets/1/5/O/1/-/-/vlookup.gif))</sub>